# Is serverfault too broad?

Tags: discussion, questions, serverfault, usability, meta

How do you consume the flood of serverfault data on a daily basis?

The favorite & ignore tags helps a bit, but I still find it to be a flood of information that is hard to digest.  Sub/more specifics sites like the ones currently being proposed in Area-51 are really interesting (such as [Telecommunications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40212/telecommunications), [Networking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering)) to me for this reason.

What discovery methods are there then to help 'bubble up' topics that are of interest to me?

Are there any tools, add-ons or extras that you use to better utilize the stack exchange forums?  There used to be a Firefox add-on that provided some filter of tags, but it is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 6):

I don't worry about reading every question that might interest me. I have favorite tags, but don't ignore anything. If something catches my eye, I read it. Life's too short to worry about the rest.

That said, this seems to be a topic that has come up over and over. Site Proposals like Networking.SE are 100% overlap with SF, and on historical basis shouldn't be allowed. But there seems to be a growing number of people who don't want the topics of Technology Administration, Engineering, and Architecture to be commingled.

At the same time some people don't want the community fractured. Most people choose a single site and only visit it on a frequent basis, the other sites lose out on their expertise on other fields. I fit squarely in this camp, but I can understand the other point of view.

There's a perfect, concise argument going on in the [Merge Telecomm with Networking Proposals Question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/merge-with-network-engineering). TL;DR Version: Telecomm is for "carriers and ISPs", Networking is for Corporate. One persons wants the sites organized by technology, which is almost completely overlap. The other wants the sites organized by audience (fearing the slightly different perspectives will cause people to "wander off").

Stack Exchange's current structure leaves no middle ground, which is a shame.

Comment: I'd LOVE a networking.SE, storage.SE..

Comment: But would you really visit both on a regular basis? I believe I've seen it happen enough times to say, no, you wont. You will pick one of them that's your "favorite" and only visit that regularly. So the other site(s) lose out on what you might have contributed. I'd love to see a Stack Exchange where you can personally aggregate what were multiple sites (so pauska.SE shows what used to be Networking.SE, Storage.SE, and SF for example).

Comment: All of my +1s for: `Most people choose a single site and only visit it on a frequent basis, the other sites lose out on their expertise on other fields.`

Comment: I never go to Unix.SE, for instance... Even though there's plenty of overlap.

Comment: I agree. Chris, that really is a great idea.

Comment: Is there any way to make a "feed" or view of multiple sites in one window? The "Stack Exchange->Hot questions" feed at the top comes from all the sites.